# Sitecore Analytics compared to Adobe Analytics? JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sitecore, adobe-analytics

I know very little about Sitecore Analytics (with MongoDB). I was wondering if there is a Javascript API that can be leveraged for non-Sitecore websites? If so could you please point me to the documentation? Also any feedback/insight would be appreciated on Sitecore Analytics. My company is considering moving to Sitecore Analytics after using Adobe Analytics and Target for years (using DTM). We have other web properties that don't use Sitecore and would need to be able to run Sitecore Analytics on these sites as well. Finally would there even be the possibility of using Adobe DTM to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how Adobe Analytics works. For Sitecore, you can use [Federated Experience Manager](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/federated_experience_manager/using_fxm/add_an_external_website_in_fxm) (FXM) for non-Sitecore sites:

> The Federated Experience Manager (FXM) is an application that allows
>   you to track visitor interactions and generate analytics information
>   on external, non-Sitecore websites.

Information on Sitecore Analytics in general can be found in their [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/analyzing__reporting/analytics):

> Sitecore Experience Analytics contains tools that let you view detailed reports
>   about your website's visitors in real time. You can use these reports
>   to give your sales team relevant information about visitors to your
>   website, which they can use to refine campaigns and optimize
>   conversion rates.

Comment: What about doing custom element level tracking? Can SiteCore Analytics do that on 3rd party sites?

Comment: E.g. Scrap a page for a specific text and based on that test perform some action?

Comment: As far as I know that would require some custom coding.

Comment: So SiteCore Analytics is only page level metrics and not element level?

Comment: It can do a lot - too much too explain here.. You should check the docs. I'm not sure how far FXM can go ootb on an non-Sitecore site though.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to the Sitecore Analytics database, you can use this connection from http://sitecorepro.blogspot.com.by/2015/06/starting-with-sitecore-analytics.html

```
//Connecting to the Analytics DB
var driver = Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbDriver.FromConnectionString("analytics");

//Building our query
var builder = new QueryBuilder();
var filter = builder.And(builder.GTE(_ => _.StartDateTime, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)), builder.EQ(_ => _.SiteName, siteName.ToLower())); 

//Retrieving data from the "Interactions" collection
var interactions = driver.Interactions.FindAs(filter)
```